# Ubuntu Samba share files with different passwords?

Tags: password

I am trying to figure out how to make separate passwords for all of my shared folders.

For example.

```
[Share Name]
path = /location/of/directory
guest ok = yes
browseable = yes
read only = no
```

I want the password for this to be 123 (As example)

```
[Share Name]
path = /location/of/directory
guest ok = yes
browseable = yes
read only = no`
```

And the password for this to be 456 (As example)

Is there any way to do this or am i stuck in the dirt?

Comment: Do you want two different shares with different passwords or two different passwords for the same share?  Could you clarify?

Comment: I want two shares with different passwords in this egsample but when i put it into use there will be saparate passwords for all 15 shares.

Comment: As far as i know, there is no possibility to base security on shared based on passwords only (former option `security = share` is strongly discouraged).  You will have to define users, give them a password and, share per share, decide which user has access right to it.